# Ошибка при запуске проекта в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio

Здравствуйте. Использую Ubuntu 14.04 и Android Studio 2.1. При попытке запуска проекта появляется ошибка:

> "Error:android-apt-compiler: [project-name]
>   Android/Sdk/build-tools/24.0.0-preview/aapt: 5:
>   Android/Sdk/build-tools/24.0.0-preview/aapt: Syntax error: end of file
>   unexpected (expecting ")")"

Подскажите пожалуйста, как ее решить?

Comment: переустановить sdk android

Comment: не пользуйтесь превью версиями build-tools